# Send blob from js form with axios, get it with php and insert it in mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, axios, blob

After searching for a while, I'm still stuck and I need help.

For a personnal project, I need a js form where information are asked and also a photo.
A js script allows to select a part of the photo and converts the photo to correct size and extension (first cropper-js and after image-conversion).
With this, I have a blob file.

```
      var params = new URLSearchParams();
      params.append("data1", document.data1);
      params.append("data2", document.data2);
      params.append("data3", document.data3);
      params.append("data4", document.data4);
      params.append("blob", blob);
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      };
      axios.post(url_to_php_file, params, config).then((res) => {
        console.log(blob);
      }
```

In console.log, I can see my blob object (size change if I change photo)
`Blob {size: 49759, type: 'image/jpeg'}`

With php, I insert in mysql db

```
    function fonctioninsert($table,$valeurs) {
        global $bdd;
        global $prefix_tables;
        $requete = 'INSERT INTO '.$prefix_tables.$table.'(';
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($valeurs as $key => $value) {
            if ($i != 0) {
                $requete .= ',';
            }
            $requete .= $key;
            $i++;
        }
        $i = 0;
        $requete .= ') VALUE (';
        foreach ($valeurs as $key => $value) {
            if ($i != 0) {
                $requete .= ',';
            }
            $requete .= "'".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
        $requete .= ')';
        $req = $bdd->prepare($requete);
        $req->execute();
        //$req->closeCursor();
        return $req;
    }


            $table = "table1";
            unset($valeurs);
            $valeurs = array(
                "data1" => $_POST["data1"],
                "data2" => $_POST["data2"],
                "data3" => $_POST["data3"],
                "data4" => $_POST["data4"],
                "blob" => $_POST["blob"]
            );
            fonctioninsert($table,$valeurs);
```

The process inserts data in db but the blob column (LONGBLOB type) is still the same with 13 o. size even if I change photo.
I tried with $_FILE but in this case, I have nothing in mysql blob column.

It's like php receive nothing and/or insert a empty blob in db.

Does anyone know where I'm faulty ?

Comment: try using `FormData` instead of `URLSearchParams`

Comment: I would also test what value javascript transfers to php in the blob parameter. If that value is already incorrect, then you know  that the issue is not with php and mysql

Comment: I tried but with FormData, I have always nothing in mysql blob column.

Comment: Good idea to check what I send. In js script, before appending params, I have a blob object but after appending, I have a file in my values then php receive a file and not a blob. I have to convert the file into blob before insert it in mysql. I tried with file_get_contents but without success yet. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the issue is with the append.
Before the append, I have a blob file but after, I have a file then the PHP script receive an file and can't insert it in a mysql blob column.
As I'm not able to convert the file to blob with php on my server, I finally chose to use file saving instead mysql and it's working well.